# Partitioning a dataset with a for loop

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset, subset

I am trying to make a function in R which returns a list of dataframes which are subsetted by each factor level.

An example to help explain what I am trying to do;

```
#Creating a dataset for my example
f1<-c("a","a","b","b","c","c")
f2<-c("x","y","x","y","x","y")
v1<-c(1:6)
v2<-c(7:12)
factors<-as.data.frame(cbind(f1,f2))
integers<-as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))
df<-cbind(factors,integers)



#The function
partition<-function(data){

   factors<-Filter(is.factor,data)    #Splitting data into factors 
   subsets<-list(NULL)              #Creating an empty list where I 
                                      will put the subsets      nm=0
  for( i  in 1:ncol(factors)){
    nm=nm+nlevels(factors[,i])
  }
  nm

   for( i in 1:ncol(factors)){  

       for(j in 1:nlevels(factors[,i])){  
          for(k in 1:nm){
            subsets[[k]]<-df[which(factors[,i]==levels(factors[,i])[j]), ] 
          }                       
       }
    }

  return(subsets)
}

partition(df)
```

This yields:

```
[[1]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12

[[2]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12

[[3]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12

[[4]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12

[[5]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12
```

As you can see, these are all the same datasets. By removing the loop over k, all the datasets are different and subsetting properly however it only gives me three datasets (as there are two levels in the last factor variable we keep the subset where `f1 == "c"`).

Removing the for loop over k we get;

```
[[1]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
1  a  x  1  7
3  b  x  3  9
5  c  x  5 11

[[2]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
2  a  y  2  8
4  b  y  4 10
6  c  y  6 12

[[3]]
  f1 f2 v1 v2
5  c  x  5 11
6  c  y  6 12
```

Where we are missing the subsets where `f1 == "a"` and `f1 == "b"`

Note I should get 5 dataframes as we have 2 + 3 factor levels (This is calculated as `nm` in the first for loop before the subsetting.

So my question is, how do I get the above to run without overiding what had already be subsetted?

For some background, this is working towards making a classification model where It would yield `nfactor(df)` predictions, then I will run a GLM to weight each prediction.

Thank you for any insight into my problem.

***Update***
The first answer from Glen simplifies my code which may make the problem I am having more apparent. Here is the updated code (note it runs much more effectively on large datasets with the `split()` function so thank you Glen.

```
for(k in 1:nm){
        for( i in 1:ncol(factors)){
          for( j in 1:nlevels(factors[,i])){
            subsets[[k]]<-split(df,factors[,i])[j]
          }
        }
      }
```

Returns the same as my original question . The problem is that when I run a loop over k through nm, the loop over writes what was already generated. How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly.  You can do this real easily with the split function.

```
f1<-c("a","a","b","b","c","c")
f2<-c("x","y","x","y","x","y")
v1<-c(1:6)
v2<-c(7:12)
factors<-as.data.frame(cbind(f1,f2))
integers<-as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))
df<-cbind(factors,integers)


tmp1=split(df,f1)
tmp2=split(df,f2)
c(tmp1,tmp2)
```

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, This simplifies my code, however I still get the same problem. I need a list of nm dataframes, when using `split(df,factors[,i])` I still get over writing and 5 identical dataframes are returned. I cannot do it by using split manually as I will have ~30 variables in my actual dataset. Thank you for the split function though, it would have saved me some time!

Comment: Is nm=5?  I've modified the answer, now you have a list of 5 data sets, isn't this what you want?  Why the for-loops?

Comment: Are you aware of the 'plyr' package?  Look at function 'dlply'

Comment: Glen, the for loops were to try minimise the time typing in variable names as I 30 variables in my dataset. @HEITZ, I had heard of that package but was unsure of its applications. However it has solved my problem with a little work. I will post an answer of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
x<-foreach(i= colnames(Filter(is.factor,df)), .combine='c') %do% 
plyr::dlply(df, i)
```

Returns a list of 5 dataframes. c is used to combine each result of the foreach loop (which is a list in itself). Without this we get a list of lists. With c, it combinds all the lists into 1 lists.